# Problema com o hook useEffect

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou com um problema que funciona da seguinte maneira, possuo uma função que ela tem que ser executada dentro do userEffect uma vez, porém o userEffect sempre executa duas vezes e eu não sei o motivo, já procurei aqui muitas soluções e todas dão a mesma resposta que é ou utilizar o parâmetro do useEffect so com isso [] ou utilizar useCallback, mas nenhum método funcionou e eu testei até com algo bem simples, vou botar o código aqui.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    teste();
  },[])
  function teste (){
    console.log('teste')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      Ola teste
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Não entendo o motivo que avaliem mal essa pergunta, é tão simples e objetiva, eu só tenho uma dúvida, executar algo dentro do hook uma vez, coloquei um exemplo e descrevi bem, acho que algumas pessoas julgam pelo que conseguem ou não conseguem responder, só se for assim para dar uma avaliação negativa. Até mesmo utilizei um exemplo basico.

Comment: Eu ouvi uma treta de que no react 18, em modo de desenvolvimento, os useEffects rodam 2x, seria um bug da versão mais recente. Checa se isso acontece no build de produção. Ou testa instalar uma versão mais antiga do react

Os votos negativos é porque o S.O. português é o esgoto da internet. Infelizmente tem que usar o em inglês.

Comment: Valeu cara, vou testar isso ai que falou, por enquanto a solução que encontrei foi tipo, colocar um verificador e na primeira passada ele muda o valor de uma variavel que so entra no if na segunda vez, gambiarra ne.

Comment: O engraçado que não procede? qual versão é o seu react?

Comment: a mais atual a minha versao

Answer (score 0):

Agora com a versão 18 do React, ao usar o Strict Mode, sempre que um componente for montado, o React simulará a desmontagem e a remotagem do componente. E isso só acontece no momento do desenvolvimento. Caso não queira esse comportamento, então pode remover o Strict Mode.
Para saber mais, segue o link da própria do React documentação, que fala sobre isso:
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: não é possível que deram downvote